# Serialize Vector3d datatype in photon unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, photon

I want to use vector3d datatype in PUN RPC parameter but Photon doesn't accept vector3d. We need to register and serialize it to use in RPC method. I am having some issues with the serialization code.

```
namespace VoxelPlay
{
    internal static class MyCustomDataType
    {
        
        internal static void Register()
        {

            PhotonPeer.RegisterType(typeof(Vector3d), (byte)'V', SerializeVector3d, DeserializeVector3d);

        }

        public static readonly byte[] memVector3d = new byte[3 * 4];

        private static short SerializeVector3d(StreamBuffer outStream, object customobject)
        {
            Vector3d vo = (Vector3d)customobject;

            int index = 0;
            lock (memVector3d)
            {
                byte[] bytes = memVector3d;
                Protocol.Serialize(vo.x, bytes, ref index);      //Getting error: Cannot convert from double to short
                Protocol.Serialize(vo.y, bytes, ref index);
                Protocol.Serialize(vo.z, bytes, ref index);
                outStream.Write(bytes, 0, 3 * 4);
            }
            return 3 * 4;
        }

        private static object DeserializeVector3d(StreamBuffer inStream, short length)
        {
            Vector3d vo = new Vector3d();
            lock (memVector3d)
            {
                inStream.Read(memVector3d, 0, 3 * 4);
                int index = 0;
                Protocol.Deserialize(out vo.x, memVector3d, ref index);
                Protocol.Deserialize(out vo.y, memVector3d, ref index);
                Protocol.Deserialize(out vo.z, memVector3d, ref index);
            }

            return vo;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you trying to cast vo.x, vo.y, vo.z to double for getting rid of the commented error.

Comment: Okay I will try this

Comment: @JesúsNarváez if the error already says that the given `double` can not be converted to `short` (the type the method expects) then casting the (already!) `double` value to `double` won't help much ;)

Comment: I have solved this issue by converting the vector3d datatype to vector3 by extracting the x, y and z coordinates. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[`ExitGames.Client.Photon.Protocol.Serialize`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/dotnet/current/class_exit_games_1_1_client_1_1_photon_1_1_protocol.html) indeed only (de)serializes `short`, `int` or `float`.

However, you could easily define your very own `double` (de) serialization e.g. using [`BitConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter) and/or [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.buffer.blockcopy)

Note that your array was wrong anyway! A [`double` has not `4` but rather `8` bytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/sizeof)

I would recommend you use `sizeof` for this kind of things ;)

```
internal static class MyCustomDataType
{
    internal static void Register()
    {
        PhotonPeer.RegisterType(typeof(Vector3d), (byte)'V', SerializeVector3d, DeserializeVector3d);
    }

    // Note: Your array had the wrong length anyway!
    // double is not 4 but 8 bytes!
    // Instead of magic numbers rather use sizeof in general
    public const short ByteSize = 3 * sizeof(double);
    public static readonly byte[] memVector3d = new byte[ByteSize];

    private static short SerializeVector3d(StreamBuffer outStream, object customobject)
    {
        var vo = (Vector3d)customobject;

        var index = 0;
        lock (memVector3d)
        {
            ToBytes(vo.x, memVector3d, ref index);      
            ToBytes(vo.y, memVector3d, ref index);
            ToBytes(vo.z, memVector3d, ref index);
            outStream.Write(memVector3d, 0, ByteSize);
        }
        return ByteSize;
    }

    private static object DeserializeVector3d(StreamBuffer inStream, short length)
    {
        var vo = new Vector3d();
        lock (memVector3d)
        {
            inStream.Read(memVector3d, 0, ByteSize);
            int index = 0;
            ReadDouble(out vo.x, memVector3d, ref index);
            ReadDouble(out vo.y, memVector3d, ref index);
            ReadDouble(out vo.z, memVector3d, ref index);
        }

        return vo;
    }

    private static void byte[] ToBytes(double input, byte[] bytes, ref offset)
    {
        // Converts the double to a byte[] of length "sizeof(double)" (=8)
        var doubleBytes = BitConverter.ToBytes(input);
        // Copy the content of the doubleSize into the combined bytes
        // starting at current offset
        Buffer.BlockCopy(doubleBytes, 0, bytes, offset, doubleBytes.Length);
        // increase by the copied size
        offset += doubleBytes.Length;
    }

    private static void ReadDouble(out double value, byte[] bytes, ref offset)
    {
        // Reads "sizeof(double)" (=8) byes starting at given offset
        // and converts them to a double
        value = BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, offset);
        // Increase by the amount of read bytes
        offset+=sizeof(double);
        return output;
    }
}
```

---

Or a probably slightly more efficient approach would be to use the `Buffer.BlockCopy` directly for converting the values like

```
internal static class MyCustomDataType
{
    internal static void Register()
    {
        PhotonPeer.RegisterType(typeof(Vector3d), (byte)'V', SerializeVector3d, DeserializeVector3d);
    }

    // Note: Your array had the wrong length anyway!
    // double is not 4 but 8 bytes!
    // Instead of magic numbers rather use sizeof in general
    public const short ByteSize = 3 * sizeof(double);
    public static readonly byte[] memVector3d = new byte[ByteSize];
    public static readonly double[] doubles = new double[3];

    private static short SerializeVector3d(StreamBuffer outStream, object customobject)
    {
        var vo = (Vector3d)customobject;

        lock (memVector3d)
        {
            // Fill the doubles array
            doubles[0] = vo.x;
            doubles[1] = vo.y;
            doubles[2] = vo.z;

            // directly copy that array on the bytes level
            Buffer.BlockCopy(floats, 0, memVector3d, 0, ByteSize);
            
            outStream.Write(memVector3d, 0, ByteSize);
        }
        return ByteSize;
    }

    private static object DeserializeVector3d(StreamBuffer inStream, short length)
    {
        var vo = new Vector3d();
        lock (memVector3d)
        {
            inStream.Read(memVector3d, 0, ByteSize);

            // Just the other way round directly copy into the doubles array on byte level
            Buffer.BlockCopy(memVector3d, 0, floats, 0, ByteSize);
            
            vo.x = doubles[0];
            vo.y = doubles[1];
            vo.z = doubles[2];
        }

        return vo;
    }
}
```

---

And now allow me the question: Do you really need `Vector3d` with `double` values?

Basically everything in Unity uses `float` anyway so at some point you will lose precision anyway. So why not already lose the precision while synchronizing?

And afaik the [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) has built-in support in Photon so no custom code has to be written/maintained.

---

As alternative if losing precision is ok while synchronizing but you still want to use `Vector3d` you could probably simply use

```
Protocol.Serialize((float)vo.x, bytes, ref index);
Protocol.Serialize((float)vo.y, bytes, ref index);
Protocol.Serialize((float)vo.z, bytes, ref index);
```

And then for receiving just make sure it uses the `float` version

```
Protocol.Deserialize(out float x, memVector3d, ref index);
Protocol.Deserialize(out float y, memVector3d, ref index);
Protocol.Deserialize(out float z, memVector3d, ref index);

vo.x = x;
vo.y = y;
vo.z = z;
```

But then again, why not simply use `Vector3` in the first place, assuming it is supported directly as mentioned before.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am developing a voxel play game and I want the voxelCenter datatype which is vector3d to be passed in the parameter in RPC.